# Script not recognizing sudo password and fails

Tags: bash, ubuntu, root, sudo, chmod

So I have this little script that runs sudo apt-get upgrade and update automatically (even answers if I want to upgrade or not), but when I run it through `./sync.sh` it prompts me for my password, even tho I declared it into the script.

Does anyone know what's going on?

*sync.sh*

```
#Colors
green=$(tput setaf 2)
normal=$(tput sgr0)

clear
echo password | yes | sudo -S apt-get upgrade

echo "${green}-------- APT-GET UPGRADE DONE --------${normal}"

echo password | yes | sudo -S apt-get update

echo "${green}-------- APT-GET UPDATE DONE ---------${normal}"
```

The output is the following:

```
Sorry, try again.
Sorry, try again.
Sorry, try again.
sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts
-------- APT-GET UPGRADE DONE --------
Sorry, try again.
Sorry, try again.
Sorry, try again.
sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts
-------- APT-GET UPDATE DONE --------
```

Comment: `echo password | sudo -S apt-get -y upgrade` or  `sudo -S apt-get -y upgrade <<< password` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may lay in the fact that `echo password | yes` returns forever

```
y
y
y
```

Try to use `xargs`:

```
echo password | xargs yes
```

or simply `yes` without pipe

```
yes password
```